# EXCEL: Read the Text of a Cell, which tells another Cell where to look at

Tags: excel

is it possible to tell Excel to read the Cell it should be looking at out of the Text that has been entered into another cell? Like for example:

```
-------------
| A | B | C |
-------------
 B1 | 5 | =CELL(A1)
```

- Cell A1 says that Excel should take the content from Cell B1
- Cell B1 contains the Value
- Cell C1 "asks" cell A1 where it should be looking at to get the Value from. The output of this formula should be "5"

Thank you

Cheers

Comment: You can use `indirect` formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes use INDIRECT():

In C1:

```
=INDIRECT(A1)
```

[image]

Just some notes about INDIRECT.  It is a Volatile function.  It will recalculate everytime that Excel Recalculates, whether the underlying data has changed or not.

Comment: Thats great already thanks. I also tried to write the col in A1 and the line in A2 and combined that using =INDIRECT(A1&A2) which did work out as well - but what doesn't work is if I want to do that for another Table (Table2). How would you do that?

Comment: @Aurus that is another question, but you need to build the string as if you entered it, so if the reference where `'Sheet1'!A1` and you want to put the sheet in one cell(A1) the Columns in another (A2) and the row in another (A3) then you would build the string: `=INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!" & A2 & A3)`